# The gaps between my variables wont appear in the browser

Tags: javascript

Just a bit confused on why the gaps between my variables will not appear. For your information, I am using sublime text 3, and launching everything on the internet explorer browser.

```js
var num1 = 10;
var num2 = 45;

var sum = num1 + num2;
var product = num1 * num2;
var divide = num1 / num2;
var mod = num1 % num2;

document.write(sum + '' + product + '' + divide + '' + mod);
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Learning Javascript</h1>
  <p>With Andrew Milicevic</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Gaps? All I see are pairs of quotes with no spaces between them. `''`

Comment: Change each empty string `''` to include a space character between the quotes: `' '`.

Comment: Shouldn't that place a gap between my answers on the browser once its run?

Comment: Oh, I see what the issue is now! Thanks Guys.

Comment: @AMilicevic You should mark Beau Smith's answer as the accepted answer (click the tick) since it's correct.

Comment: @Clonkex Thank for letting me know, just did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a space character between your quotes: `''` vs `' '`.

Try this:

```js
var num1 = 10;
var num2 = 45;

var sum = num1 + num2;
var product = num1 * num2;
var divide = num1 / num2;
var mod = num1 % num2;

document.write(sum + ' ' + product + ' ' + divide + ' ' + mod);
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Learning Javascript</h1>
  <p>With Andrew Milicevic</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
</div>
```